# Where are the downloads from the Browser stored and how to I get to downloads from the browser?

Tags: browser, samsung-galaxy-nexus

Using a Galaxy Nexus I download an apk and it showed up in the notifications bar when it was done downloading. I went to install but I didn't set option to allow external apps so I did that and I went back to the browser to install the apk and couldn't find it. It wasn't in the notifications anymore and there didn't seem to be a "downloads" option anywhere in the browser. I ended up having to download it again just so it would be in the notifications so I could then get to the apk to install it. And I downloaded it AGAIN to show a friend the issue. Now I'd like to delete all three and know where to go next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There should be a "Downloads" app in your app drawer. Open it to view your downloads. Previous versions of Android (up to Gingerbread, AFAIK, possibly Honeycomb) had a "Downloads" option in the Browser itself under `Menu->More->Downloads`, but it's possible this no longer exists on ICS.

Alternatively, if you have a file manager they should be in `/sdcard/download`, I believe (on ICS [this actually appears to have changed](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19039/where-are-the-downloads-from-the-browser-stored-and-how-to-i-get-to-downloads-fr/19040#comment22067_19040) to `/sdcard/Download` with a capital 'D'). It can vary by device a bit, but generally it should be `/<whatever_your_"sdcard"_path_is>/download`.

Comment: On my stock Galaxy Nexus, my downloaded files are in /sdcard/Download

Comment: @Malachi: Hm, weird that they decided to change the casing like that, but good to know!